# run a command with double quote in new window in Alacritty

Tags: shell, terminal, alacritty

I can run

```
gnome-terminal  -- journalctl --since "10min ago" -f
```

What is the equivalent of this command for alacitty.

I tried

```
alacritty -e "journalctl --since \"10min ago\" -f"
alacritty -e "journalctl --since '10min ago' -f"
alacritty -e 'journalctl --since "10min ago" -f'
```

every command returns

```
Error: Failed to spawn command 'journalctl --since '10min ago' -f': No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: Did you try _not_ quoting the whole command?

Comment: `alacritty -e journalctl --since "10min ago" -f` works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alacritty` will use the arguments after the `-e` option as the command to execute.  Since the terminal uses the first argument after `-e` as the utility name, quoting the whole command will make the terminal use the complete command string as the utility name, which will fail.

Instead, remove the quotes around the command.  This allows `alacritty` to distinguish between the utility name and its arguments.

Note too that `-e` needs to be the last option on `alacritty`'s command line.

In short: `-e` in `alacritty` works like `--` in `gnome-terminal`.